# A video cropper for Windows 10

Tags: windows, gratis, video-editing

I'm looking for a simple video cropper to windows 10, I mean something that I can download for free and crop to instagram stories without need a phone.

Comment: By cropping you really mean changing the size. Not trimming the beginning and the end?

Answer (score 1):

[ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) is mostly used by other programs tool for working with video. It is commandline crossplatform tool (there is no GUI), but it is very powerful and I think, it would work fine for you.

[Here is the command for cropping](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/4571):

```
ffmpeg -i "smth.mp4" -filter:v "crop=width:height:x:y" "smth cropped.mp4"
```

where

- `smth.mp4` - name of the file to be cropped
- `width` should be replaced by desired width of resulting file's frame
- `height` should be replaced by desired height of resulting file's frame
- `x` should be replaced by x-coordinate of point you are going to crop from
- `y` should be replaced by y-coordinate of point you are going to crop from
- `smth cropped.mp4` - name of the resulting file

Answer (score 0):

I found the perfect and free answer, I was looking for a simple way to crop videos for instagram stories, and better than just a software I found the following online converter:
https://www.kapwing.com

I recommend it because was fast and simple.

Comment: Unfortunate that this is an online tool...